# MongoDB aggregate with group by nested field and count by another field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, facet

I've three different documents as follows

```
{
  "category" : "aaaaa",
  "summary" : {
    "details" : {
      "city" : "abc"
      "year_of_reg" : "2012",
      "dept" : "dev"
    }
  }
}

{
  "category" : "bbbb",
  "summary" : {
    "details" : {
      "city" : "abc",
      "year_of_reg" : "2016",
      "dept" : "dev"
    }
  }
}

{
  "category" : "aaaaa",
  "summary" : {
    "details" : {
      "dept" : "ui",
      "year_of_reg" : "2018"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to group the results based on the keys available in details under summary and count based on category. The final result should be like as below

```
{
  "dep_dev":[
      {
         "category":"aaaaa",
         "count":1.0
      },
      {
         "category":"bbbb",
         "count":1.0
      }
   ],
   "dep_ui":[
      {
         "category":"aaaaa",
         "count":1.0
      }
   ],
   "year_of_reg_2012":[
      {
         "category":"aaaaa",
         "count":1.0
      }
   ],
   "year_of_reg_2016":[
      {
         "category":"bbbb",
         "count":1.0
      }
   ],
   "year_of_reg_2018":[
      {
         "category":"aaaaa",
         "count":1.0
      }
   ],      
   "city_abc":[
      {
         "category":"aaaaa",
         "count":1.0
      },
      {
         "category":"bbbb",
         "count":1.0
      }
   ]
}
```

How this can be achieved in mongo aggregate? Can this be done using facet? 
How output keys can be generated dynamically in aggregate? Is there any possible way to get all the keys available under details using a single mongo query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to run the following aggregate pipeline to get the desired results:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    /*
    1. Create a field with an array of the summary details key concatenated with their 
       corresponding values. 
    */
    { "$addFields": { 
        "summary": {
            "$map": {
                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$summary.details" },
                "as": "el",
                "in": {
                    "$concat": ["$$el.k", "_", "$$el.v"]
                }
            }
        }
    } },

    /*
    2. Flatten the new array to produce a copy of each document per array entry. 
    */
    { "$unwind": "$summary" },

    /*
    3. Group the documents initially by the key and category. 
    */
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "key": "$summary",
            "category": "$category"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    } },

    /*
    4. Group the input documents from the previous pipeline by the key and aggregate the 
       category and corresponding counts  
    */
    {  "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.key",
        "counts": {
            "$push": {
                "category": "$_id.category",
                "count": "$count"
            }
        }
    } },

    /*
    4. Calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole.
    */
    {  "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "counts": {
            "$push": {
                "k": "$_id",
                "v": "$counts"
            }
        }
    } },
    { "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" }
    } } 
])
```

Comment: It's almost the same my answer below.

Comment: @ngocchien I agree, there are some similaraties with your answer and mine e.g. the use of `$objectToArray`, the key name `summary` and `$concat`. However, there are notable differences with the pipelines; I'm using a single pipeline `$map` to create an array of new keys and I can point out several flaws with your answer I'm afraid. To begin with, your first `$project` pipeline will throw an error on `"details": { $objectToArray: "details"}` because it won't recognise `"details"` as a field, missing the `$` keyword also it's not an embedded document.

Comment: @ngocchien Also even if the whole aggregate pipeline is corrected it won't produce the desired results the OP seeks, you would still need further pipelines like regrouping the counts to calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole and pipe them to a final `"$replaceRoot"` pipeline.

Comment: Yes, I agree there are some misspellings in my answer. I just gave the idea. I even haven't tested the result yet. Anyway, I think our idea is true and it's the most important, and the asker will know how to correct to her need.

Comment: Thanks @chridam. It worked perfectly. There are two things for me to consider here. 1) The results are shuffled. I need it to be sorted by the total count based on keys under details in summary (dept, city, year_of_reg) and if two keys has same number of count, it should be sorted alphabetically (edited the expected response in question) 2) $addToFields is new in Mongo 3.4. How the above query can be modified for Mongo 2.4

Comment: @NagaLakshmi Unfortunately aggregation framework in 2.4 lacks the operators needed to get the keys in a document as well as the ones required to replace the root otherwise you may have to use MapReduce for this. As for sorting the results, place a `$sort` pipeline just after the `$unwind` to get them into the next pipeline in order.

Comment: @chridam sort after unwind is not working properly since I need a first level sort by keywise overall count. For eg: All the documents have city key. That should be coming first in the result. The second level sort is alphabetical if multiple keys are having same overall count.

Comment: @chridam seems the documents has first to be sorted based on the key count and then processed to bring the final result. But I'm unable achieve this. Could you please provide me the updated query

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps: 
Transform the "detail" object to array by $objectToArray. Now, the detail field looks like `"details: [{k: "city", v: "abc"}, {v: "dep", k: "dev"}]`

$unwind the "details" array field.

$project the new label `"label: $details.k_$details.v"`.

$group by both the new label, and category.

$group by the category.

```
db.collections.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        "category": 1,
        "details": { $objectToArray: "details"}
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "details"
},
{
    $project: {
        "label": { $concat ["$details.k", '_', "$details.v"]}
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        "_id": {
            "label": "label",
            "category": "category"
        },
        "count": {$sum: 1}
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        "_id": "_id.label",
        "summary": {
            $push: {
                "category": "$_id.category",
                "count": "$count"
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```